# Jira running as cluster but always reporting node1 being used

Tags: cluster-analysis, jira

I have three Jira nodes configured as cluster behind a load balancer.

Network traffic (tcpdump etc) suggests that traffic is routed to all three nodes yet the Jira landing page is always showing node01 at the bottom (see screenshot below).

When I check Jira logs it does suggest node01 is the cluster master by election but still does this mean it'll serve all requests ?

Is that all by design or do I need to revisit my cluster configuration ?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting in a different browser to see you are given a different node. There is no concept of a cluster master. Check Admin, System Info to see whether all nodes are active and in the cluster. And double check your cluster.properties file has a different name on each node

Our cluster.properties template looks like this:

```html
# This ID must be unique across the cluster
jira.node.id = <nodeid>
# The location of the shared home directory for all JIRA nodes
jira.shared.home = /mnt/abc/jira_data_shared
ehcache.peer.discovery = default
ehcache.listener.hostName = <servername>
```

We hard code the hostname in each cluster.properties file instead of using multicast. More info at https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/configuring-a-jira-cluster/

Comment: I didn't make up these logs suggesting there is ? 2021-09-10 20:33:55,406+0000 dataplane-ET-0:0907191920 DEBUG      [c.a.dataplane.cluster.ElectionTask] Node 'node1' waking up for election heartbeat (shb=false)
2021-09-10 20:33:55,408+0000 dataplane-ET-0:0907191920 DEBUG      [c.arsenalesystems.dataplane.ab] Our node 'node1' is still the master and is updating the heartbeat
2021-09-10 20:33:55,416+0000 dataplane-ET-0:0907191920 DEBUG      [c.a.dataplane.cluster.ElectionTask] ElectionTask on node 'node1' sleeping for 32 seconds

Comment: Regarding cluster.properties I see two: 1) /opt/atlassian/jira/data/cluster.properties 2) /var/atlassian/application_data/jira_shared/jira/cluster.properties in the first one the nodes are correctly numbered, in the second file jira.node.id = cebb7b6d is the same on all three. Is that OK ?

Comment: Er, that's arsenalesystems, which is a plugin. Not Jira Data Center itself. Best contact them directly. Say "hi"

Comment: That is odd having two cluster.properties files.